# Scala typing with implicits gives typing error

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement this:

```
def buildQuery() {
  val restrictions: ConjunctionRestriction[String, Int] =
    ("name" is "Some One") and ("age" is 20)
}

implicit def stringToEqualsRestrictionBuilder[T](fieldName: String)
                                                : EqualsRestrictionBuilder[T] =
  new EqualsRestrictionBuilder[T](fieldName)

implicit def restrictionToConjunctionBuilder[L,R](restriction: Restriction[L])
                                                 : ConjunctionBuilder[L,R] =
  new ConjunctionBuilder[L,R](restriction)

case class Restrictions(restrictions: Restriction[_]*)

trait Restriction[T] {
  def toString: String
}

class EqualsRestriction[T](val fieldName: String, val value: T)
    extends Restriction[T] {
  override def toString = fieldName + "=" + value
}

class ConjunctionRestriction[A,B](val lhs: Restriction[A],
                                  val rhs: Restriction[B]) 
    extends Restriction[(A,B)] {
  override def toString = "(" + lhs + ") AND (" + rhs + ")"
}

class EqualsRestrictionBuilder[T](val fieldName: String,
                                  val restriction: Option[Restriction[T]] = None) {

  def is(value: Int) =
    new EqualsRestriction[Int](fieldName, value)

  def is(value: String) =
    new EqualsRestriction[String](fieldName, "\"" + value + "\"")
}

class ConjunctionBuilder[L,R](val lhs: Restriction[L]) {
  def and(rhs: Restriction[R]) = new ConjunctionRestriction[L,R](lhs, rhs)
}
```

The compiler gives me error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : MyOuterClass.this.EqualsRestriction[Int]
required: MyOuterClass.this.Restriction[R]
val restrictions: ConjunctionRestriction[String, Int] =
  ("name" is "Some One") and ("age" is 20)
```

I havn't had the scala type system all figured out. what is wrong with this?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Fixed by changing ConjunctionBuilder to have only one parameter type L:

```
class ConjunctionBuilder[L](val lhs: Restriction[L]) {
  def and[R](rhs: Restriction[R]) = new ConjunctionRestriction[L,R](lhs, rhs)
}

implicit def restrictionToConjunctionBuilder[L](restriction: Restriction[L])
                                               : ConjunctionBuilder[L] =
  new ConjunctionBuilder[L](restriction)
```

But could someone explain why with the R parameter type, the compile fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails when `ConjunctionBuilder` has the `R` type parameter simply because when applying the implicit conversion `restrictionToConjunctionBuilder`, the compiler can only infer `L` (from the parameter `restriction`).
The type parameter `R` does not appear anywhere in the parameter list, so there is no way it can be inferred. 
When type parameters cannot be inferred, you *have* to pass them explicitly (but of course in the case of implicit conversion, this defeats the purpose).
By example: the following compiles correctly:

```
val restrictions: ConjunctionRestriction[String, Int] =
  (("name" is "Some One"): ConjunctionBuilder[String, Int]) and ("age" is 20)
```

Short of explictly specifying the type parameters, the compiler cannot bind `R`, and thus cannot prove that the parameter to the method `and` is of the right type. 
Indeed, the method expects a `Restriction[R]`, and we give it a `Restriction[Int]`. This can only match if `R` == `Int`, which the compiler can't prove as `R` is unbound.

Your fix is totally correct: move the type parameter `R` to the definition of `and`. This way when applying the implicit conversion `restrictionToConjunctionBuilder`, the compiler can fully infer all the type parameters (that is, the uniqye type parameter `L`) from the parameter `restriction`.
Then, when applying `and` it can infer `R` from its parameter `rhs`